# Memoize with inputs that have commutative property?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, memoization

Imagine I have a function that simply sum up a list of numbers.

```js
function add(...input) {
    return input.reduce((sum, num) => sum + num, 0)
}
```

I want to memorize this function to avoid unnecessary computation so I wrote a higher order function `memoize`

```js
function memoize(fn, resolver) {
    const cache = new Map()
    
    return function(...args) {
        let key
        if(!resolver) key = args.join('')
        else key = resolver(...args)
        
        if (cache.has(key)) return cache.get(key)
        const val = fn(...args)
        cache.set(key, val)

        return val
    }
}
```

now if we give `add` the same list of numbers, it will try to get the sum from the cache first before it computes the sum.

However, the problem is that, the addition has associative property. E.g. `add(1,2,3)` and `add(2,1,3)` return the same value but the current implementation would treat them as different inputs so we have a cache miss but in reality it should be a cache hit.

Was wondering if there is any ways we can implement a cache that takes this associative property into account?

Comment: The most practical way is usually just to sort the inputs according to some arbitrary, but well-defined, order.

Comment: Your example is actually for commutative property, not associative. For your purpose, the function needs to be *both* commutative and associative.

Comment: @Barmar oops thanks for pointing that out. if it is actually commutative property, then what the function needs to be both commutative and associative?

Comment: Commutative means that `a+b == b+a`. Associative means that `a+(b+c) == (a+b)+c`. If you want `a+b+c == c+b+a` you need both.